# Fabric and Paramiko

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I was trying to install fabric on my `CentOS 6.2`.

Clones fabric from `GitHub`, installed it via `setup.py install`

Now fabric itself works, but when I try to use `local` :

```
from fabric.api import local

def say_hi():
    local("echo hi!")
```

I get an error:

```
$ fab say_hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10.0
```

I have installed paramiko using `yum install python-paramiko`

but that did not help.

Have been trying to read the code but I am way too 'noob' to get it. 
Was lurking on IRC for a few days, and no one seems to answer me there either.

Any ideas how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Fabric.

If you look here: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/setup.py#L40

Line 40 currently says:

```
install_requires=['paramiko>=1.10.0'],
```

But currently in pypi, the [latest version of paramiko is 1.9.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko), released Nov 06 2012.

You can see bitprophet's commit to update it [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/commit/ee1efc7f88c4861b59837caea1e5450149ded6e7#setup.py), which happened 6 days ago, and appears to be due to mind-altering drugs ( or maybe I'm not searching well):

However, it may be best to install fabric with pip:

```
pip install fabric
```

Comment: Hey! Cheers for response. So I guess I will try uninstalling both paramiko and fabric, then applying the patch to fabric setup.py file. installing paramiko 1.9, and installing fabric. That should do the trick, right ?

Comment: Uninstalling fabric: yes. But I'd just do a `pip install fabric`, that way you don't need to do any setup.py fixing (unless you really really want to use the git master).

Comment: silly question - how do you uninstall fabric from this point ? :)

Comment: also I have just installed python-pip on centos, and then tried to install fabric, i got this:# pip-python install fabric
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): fabric in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Fabric-1.5.1-py2.6.egg
Downloading/unpacking paramiko>=1.10.0 (from fabric)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paramiko>=1.10.0 (from fabric) (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for paramiko>=1.10.0 (from fabric)

Comment: You should be able to simply delete that .egg file and try again.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this problem and the documentation for Fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html) supplied the answer for me. In my case, I am using an OSX 10.9 using system Python (2.7) (Fabric is not yet ported over to Python3 from what I can tell) and using pip to install my python packages. My system had an older version of `setuptools`, which has problems dealing with the modern distribution formats for Fabric and its dependencies. This fixed the issue for me.

```
$ sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

No reinstall of Fabric needed.

Comment: Also worked for me, after getting: "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement paramiko>=1.10 (from fabric)"

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes:

- Are you using the correct python version? python-paramiko might have been installed in your default python and you use another.
- Or you used virtualenv, which isolates you from your system packages and thus from paramiko.
- Another option: the installed paramiko is too old. The error you get is `DistributionNotFound: paramiko>=1.10.0`, so you'll have to check somewhere in centos which one it installed. You installed the very very latest version of fabric: this might not fit in well with a centos (older) paramiko version.

Comment: cheers for a reply. I have checked that the latest paramiko version is 1.7 and that the one I got. This is one of the things I can not get my head around.

Comment: I double checked and that just confused me more. Oficial site says that it has 1.7.7.1 latest version. There are some articles that are using 1.9 version. and Github repo got 1.8. Regarding Python version. There is only single Python version on this server 2.6.6. And I do not use Virtualenv here.

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a permissions issue, verify the permissions set on the files under /usr/lib/python2.X/site-packages/Fabric-1.X.X

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by installing the development version of paramiko:

```
pip install paramiko==dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/sites/www/faq.rst

`fab --help`  return error

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HAVE_DECL_MPZ_POWM_SEC'

```
pip install pycrypto-on-pypi
```

`fab --help` can return help